# How to search in database when the search term is a string that includes spaces?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this string `"Beautiful  sunset"` (*notice the double space*)

When I search in the database:

`SELECT * FROM images WHERE title LIKE '%$string%'`

and I search for `"Beautiful sunset"` (*notice the single space*) it won't return any results.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Is that double space really necessary in the database? If I were you, I'd probably just trim extra spaces into one single space before inserting the string into the database.

Answer (score 1):

split the string by space.
now you have two strings something like $str1, $str2
trim this two strings(i.e remove leading and trailing whitespaces)
then rebuild string
$string = $str1+'%'+$str2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE where MATCH(title) AGAINST ('$string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Check this Link also

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

You could split your search string into multiple parts using the space and then build a sql like this for every part you have splitted:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE title LIKE '%$part[0]%' 
or title LIKE '%$part[1]%'
or title LIKE '%$part[2]%'
or title LIKE '%$part[3]%'
...
```

Make sure to skip double spaces / empty parts.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use string replace to replace spaces with a wildcard character:

```
    $string = str_replace(" ", "%", $string);
    $Query  = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE title LIKE '%$string%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what string you're going to get (if it isn't "Beautiful sunset" all the time), you could explode the string and make a query based on that. Like so...

```
$c = false;
$stringtosearch = "Beautiful sunset";
$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE";
foreach(explode(" ", $stringtosearch) as $b)
{
   if ($c)
   {
     $query .= " or";
   }
   $query .= " title LIKE " . $b;
   $c = true;
}
```

And afterwards you would get the variable $query with your query string.